# Php foreach loop not working

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

Could you help me what is wrong with this code snippet?
`$mylist` is an array of arrays, with the following structure:
`$mylist[$key] = Array ( ["name"] => a ["label"] => b ["amount"] => c ["temp"] => d )`.

Problem is the following: the first `print_r($value);` statement prints the correct array, but if I call the array's value one-by-one, the array seems to be empty.
(I copy-pasted it from another script where it worked...)

```
$mylist = $_POST['mylist'];
foreach ($mylist as $key => $value) {
            print_r($value);
            echo "<br>";
            echo "name=".$value["name"]."<br>";
            echo "label=".$value["label"]."<br>";
            echo "amount=".$value["amount"]."<br>";
            echo "temp=".$value["temp"]."<br>";
        }
```

**Edit**

Result of `print_r($value)`:

`Array ( ["name"] => a ["label"] => b ["amount"] => c ["temp"] => d )`

Result of `var_dump($mylist)`:

`array(4) { [178]=> array(4) { [""name""]=> string(1) "a" [""label""]=> string(1) "b" [""amount""]=> string(1) "c" [""temp""]=> string(1) "d" } [179]=> array(4) { [""name""]=> string(0) "" [""label""]=> string(0) "" [""amount""]=> string(0) "" [""temp""]=> string(0) "" } [180]=> array(4) { [""name""]=> string(0) "" [""label""]=> string(0) "" [""amount""]=> string(0) "" [""temp""]=> string(0) "" } [181]=> array(4) { [""name""]=> string(0) "" [""label""]=> string(0) "" [""amount""]=> string(0) "" [""temp""]=> string(0) "" } }`

**Edit 2.**

The code from which $_POST gets its input is

`'<tr><td><input type="text" name=\'myList['.$_id.']["name"]\' ></td><td><input type="text" name=\'myList['.$_id.']["label"]\' ></td><td><input type="text" name=\'myList['.$_id.']["amount"]\' ></td><td><input type="text" name=\'myList['.$_id.']["temp"]\' ></td></tr>';`

Comment: copy-pasted from which link, share that link too.

Comment: print_r($value); can you show result?

Comment: Is `Array ( ["name"] => a ["label"] => b ["amount"] => c ["temp"] => d )` a correct array format ? I think it should be alike this `array(    key  => value,    key2 => value2,    key3 => value3,    ...)` ...

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui I get the array in this form from `$_POST`

Comment: @MilanChheda I copied it from another script of mine

Comment: There is something wrong and weird with your array. May be you should correct this first before processing it. Why do they have double double-quotes?? `[""name""]`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `var_dump` output is weird. Why all keys are surrounded by two double quotes?

In your `foreach`, try `echo $value['"name"'];`. If it works, your inputs from your form are not correct.

Comment: Your question "Why all keys..." helped to make me notice the error in my html code, where I added extra quotes for the keywords name, temp etc.

Comment: Yep, double quotes are not needed in HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You key string has `"` in each side,

```
change ["name"] to ["\"name\""]
```